# making the same $http request simultaneously

Tags: angularjs

What happens if I make the same $http request - same params, etc- simultaneously in the app?  Does one wait for the others' response?

And if I make them back to back.  If the first one is not resolved yet, do the others wait for that?

Comment: You mean like having two threads running the same call? That's literally impossible because JavaScript is single-threaded

Comment: yea. if you make them back to back by calling second `$http` request inside first one, then of course, second one will wait for first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit for browsers request count See [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/985431/413032)

Think each request independent , angularjs $http service return a `promise` object and you register its success and error callbacks.

Read more about from here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

See my plunk below. If I call multiple calls I see them parallel in network tab. But this doesn't cause a conflict because we have different promises and their callbacks will be different. call 1 promise instance1 ... call N promise instance N

http://plnkr.co/edit/XUboyUiAs7KFcRhUu3LP?p=preview

[image]